# jmeter var.putobject variable use in other jdbc request, but it is ignored

Tags: jmeter

Test Plan
Thread Group
JDBC Connection
JSR223 Sampler
JDBC Request
Result Tree

Put codes in the JSR223 Sampler:

`int id =  Integer.parseInt( vars.get("party_id") ); 
vars.putObject("id", new Integer(id));`

Then use id in JDBC Request:

```
    select * from table where column = ? 
    Parameter Value: ${id}
    parameter Type： NUMBER
```

It seems the JDBC request is ignored and no output shown in the result tree.

Please help to look into the issue...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Variable stores value of `String` but not `Integer`. I wonder if there is any error/warning in JMeter console (log).

Cast you integer to String to put it into UDV.
[image]

Just specify ${UDV} if you wanted it to be an integer. Add quotes ('$UDV') if you want it as varchar in SQL query
[image]

[image]

Comment: I also add debug sampler into the test plan, variable "id" has the value shown in the result tree. Observe the issue from the log file "jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler 'try integer' : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String". Do you have any idea how to get the integer variable used in the other sampler?

Comment: When you use `putObject` method just cast your integer into String using `toString()` method. `vars.putObject("id", id.toString()); `

Comment: If i use string it works fine for my select statement where i can change the type to varchar. I have one insert statement for one jdbc request required number parameter. When i pass "${id}" not working if cast it to String.

Comment: I'm not sure I've got your option. If you have select query you write it as `select * from table where condition = ${id}`. Supposing your variable has value 5 (it is string, because user defined variable stores only string) next query will be executed `select * from table where condition = 5`. If you need varchar in the SQL query you write `select * from table where condition = '${id}'` and next will be executed `select * from table where condition = '5'`. JMeter HTTP or JDBC sampler treat ${variable} the next way: just get the text from variable and put it into sampler body. Is it the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the details. Method vars.putObject can store any type of object for user defined variable, for example integer. I wonder if there is some way to get the variable whose type is not string. I have one insert query [insert into table (id number) values (${id})] required integer in one jdbc request using the variable storing integer defined in JSR223 sampler. As you have mentioned, ${id} type is string, any way to convert to integer?

Answer (score 0):

Have reproduced your problem, it looks like that [JDBC Sampler](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65143-using-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6) doesn't accept integers, only Strings.

I'm getting following error in jmeter.log, guess you too:

> 2014/01/04 11:30:14 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error while
>   processing sampler 'JDBC Request' : java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

So your cast to integer is absolutely not required. Try changing your JSR223 code to following:

```
vars.put("id", vars.get("party_id"));
```

It should work fine.

The bit, which tells MySQL which datatype bind the variable to is `ParameterType` stanza. You need to specify paratemer type there, not in JSR223